# How to delete duplicate rows in this specific statement

Tags: sql-server

I have seen some good examples for deleting duplicate rows, but my attempts fail.  Something in this won't let it happen.  Errors don't tell me anything to help me know whats wrong with it.  I won't include it to dirty up my question.  Lets just say that this script works and gives a sequential index for each duplicate row, as DuplicateCount.  Basically all lines with a DuplicateCount > 1 need deleted.  How do I wrap this around this statement?

```sql
SELECT
    v.WONum,
    o.OrderNumber,
    o.GUIDOrder,
    v.WorkOrder,
    v.Product,
    v.BuildDate,
    v.TestDate,
    v.PassFail,
    v.Valve,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (Partition BY v.WONum, o.OrderNumber, o.GUIDOrder, v.WorkOrder, v.Product, v.BuildDate, v.TestDate, v.PassFail, v.Valve
        ORDER BY Index_VSN) AS DuplicateCount
FROM dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New AS v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [KT-RD-01\acctivate].ACCTivate$KELSOTECH.dbo.Orders AS o 
    ON v.WONum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = o.OrderNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I have tried this, and no work.

https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT?
Its normal use is to remove duplicate lines.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.WONum, o.OrderNumber, o.GUIDOrder, v.WorkOrder, v.Product, v.BuildDate, v.TestDate, v.PassFail, v.Valve, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY v.WONum, o.OrderNumber, o.GUIDOrder, v.WorkOrder, v.Product, v.BuildDate, v.TestDate, v.PassFail, v.Valve
ORDER BY Index_VSN) AS DuplicateCount FROM dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New AS v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [KT-RD-01\acctivate].ACCTivate$KELSOTECH.dbo.Orders AS o 
ON v.WONum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = o.OrderNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh... I guess I was thinking about it too complicated.  I did have to take out the DuplicateCount stuff...  This is what finally worked.  Thanks, @FelixACR

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.WONum, o.OrderNumber, o.GUIDOrder, v.WorkOrder, v.Product, v.BuildDate, v.TestDate, v.PassFail, v.Valve
FROM   dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New AS v LEFT OUTER JOIN
             [KT-RD-01\acctivate].ACCTivate$KELSOTECH.dbo.Orders AS o ON v.WONum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = o.OrderNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```